# Google Chrome: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Tags: google-chrome

I recently updated Google Chrome to 86.0.4240.75 and I keep getting this error message:

```
net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
```

I'm on a fixed local IPv4 (192.168.x) and fixed IPv6. The error appears randomly at the rate of about 1 each minute; browsing is becoming difficult, many connections are cut short (leading to blank screen and aborted POST).
ssh connection are steady.
I'm running Ubuntu 19.10

Any idea of how I can fix that?

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: It took me almost one hour to be able to post this question...